# Record video while other video is playing

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, uiimagepickercontroller, avplayer

I am using `UIImagePickerController` to record a video. and am using `AVPlayer` to play a video. and adding `AVPlayerLayer` to `UIImagePickerController's`  `cameraOverlayView` so that i can see video while recording.
My requirement is

1. I need to watch video while recording video using `UIImagePickerController`
2. using headset i need to listen audio from playing video
3. need to record my voice to recording video
4. only my voice should be recorded but not playing video's audio.

every thing working but 4. audio from playing video also mix with my voice. how to handle this case? My final goal is

1. Out put for the playing video is headset
2. Input for the recording is headset's mic

Please help me to get this done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your requirement is interesting. So you need to play and record at the same time, right?
So that, you will need to initialize audio session with the category `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`.

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error];
```

Because you are using `UIImagePickerController` to record so you don't have much control to your speaker and your mic. So test and see if it works.

In case you still have problem, I suggest you to use `AVCaptureSession` to record video without audio. Look at this example how to use it [record-video-with-avcapturesession-2](http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/camera/record-video-with-avcapturesession-2).

UPDATE: In my VOIP application, I use `AVAudioUnit` to record while playing back. So I think the only way is record video and audio separately and then use `AVComposition` to compose its to a single movie. Using `AVCaptureSession` to record video only and use [EZAudio](https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio) to record audio. The `EZAudio` use `AVAudioUnit` to record so that it should work. You can test it by record audio while playing a movie and see if it works. I hope it will help

UPDATE: I tested and it only work if you use headphone or select microphone back.
Here is the tested code:

```
    NSString *moviePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"videoviewdemo" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
    // You may find a test stream at <http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8>.
    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];

    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    AVPlayerLayer *layer = [[AVPlayerLayer alloc] init];
    [layer setPlayer:player];
    [layer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:layer];

    [player play];

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //
        // Setup the AVAudioSession. EZMicrophone will not work properly on iOS
        // if you don't do this!
        //
        AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        NSError *error;
        [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error];
        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error setting up audio session category: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }
        [session setActive:YES error:&error];
        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error setting up audio session active: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }

        //
        // Customizing the audio plot's look
        //
        // Background color
        self.audioPlot.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.984 green:0.471 blue:0.525 alpha:1.0];

        // Waveform color
        self.audioPlot.color = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];

        // Plot type
        self.audioPlot.plotType = EZPlotTypeBuffer;

        //
        // Create the microphone
        //
        self.microphone = [EZMicrophone microphoneWithDelegate:self];

        //
        // Set up the microphone input UIPickerView items to select
        // between different microphone inputs. Here what we're doing behind the hood
        // is enumerating the available inputs provided by the AVAudioSession.
        //
        self.inputs = [EZAudioDevice inputDevices];
        self.microphoneInputPickerView.dataSource = self;
        self.microphoneInputPickerView.delegate = self;

        //
        // Start the microphone
        //
        [self.microphone startFetchingAudio];
        self.microphoneTextLabel.text = @"Microphone On";

        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:nil];
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for replay, i tried AVCaptureSession having same issue.

Comment: Okey i will try with AVComposition and AVAudioUnit, But just a quick question before start can we record audio while playing back, can we avoid mixing play back audio to recording?

Comment: In a VOIP app, it is possible to record and play back in the same time. I don't think it is impossible.

Comment: I will also try it tonight and come back to you.

Comment: Thank you, i will also try.

Comment: Any progress? I can do it in my test. Read my updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83867/discussion-between-naresh-and-sahara108).

Comment: Thank you ashara108, i found github.com/syedhali/EZAudio. i can able to record audio from headset mic, and as you said i will capture video from AVCaptureSession. then i am merging them at the end of recording.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [PBJVision library](https://github.com/piemonte/PBJVision). It allows you to record video while you are watching the preview, and at the end, you can do whatever you want with audio and video footage.