# Recording a video with the front-facing camera while another video is being played on the phone.

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, video, recording

I am currently learning Swift in order to build an iOS app for my research project which involves recording someone's face while they watch a video on an iPhone. I've looked through a few tutorials on how to get a video playing and how to record video in Swift but I'm not sure on how to merge the two together. Particularly, I will have a "Play Video" button that as soon as the user presses it, the front-facing camera will start recording and a video will begin to play.

I've found this post - [Record video while other video is playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472699/record-video-while-other-video-is-playing) - that is very similar to the question that I'm asking but I don't really understand the code that is written.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try using this to covert [Objective-c to Swift](https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/main) to see if it helps and it's free up to 10kb when you sign up.